# Django celery trigger manage.py cmd @periodic_task

Tags: python, django, triggers, celery, manage.py

i want to run a manage.py cmd from celery as a periodic task every x Minutes but every time i try to accomplish that as show below i get the following error:

> [2019-01-17 01:36:00,006: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: Delete
>   unused media file(s)[3dd2b93b-e32a-4736-8b24-028b9ad8da35]
>   [2019-01-17 01:36:00,007: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] Scanning for
>   unused media files [2019-01-17 01:36:00,008: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3]
>   Unknown command: 'cleanup_unused_media --noinput --remove-empty-dirs'
>   [2019-01-17 01:36:00,008: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task Delete unused
>   media file(s)[3dd2b93b-e32a-4736-8b24-028b9ad8da35] succeeded in
>   0.0008139749998008483s: None

tasks.py

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
import requests
from django.core import management


logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://127.0.0.1')

...
@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*/90')), name="Delete unused media file(s)", ignore_result=True)
def delete_unused_media():
    try:
        print("Scanning for unused media files")
        management.call_command('cleanup_unused_media --noinput --remove-empty-dirs')
        return "success, old media files have been deleted"
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

that management cmd comes from the following project:
https://github.com/akolpakov/django-unused-media

is my management call simply wrong or whats the deal?

thanks in advance

UPDATE (Celery Config):

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'celery',
'django_unused_media',
...
# Celery Settings:
BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
...
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": [
            "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0",
            #"redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1",
        ],
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
            "SOCKET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT": 15,  # in seconds
            "SOCKET_TIMEOUT": 15,  # in seconds
            "COMPRESSOR": "django_redis.compressors.zlib.ZlibCompressor",
            "CONNECTION_POOL_KWARGS": {"max_connections": 1000, "retry_on_timeout": True}
        }
    }
}
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MyProject.settings')

app = Celery('MyProject')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()



@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

_init__.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app')
```

e.g. This task is working fine:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*/1')), name="Get exchange rate(s)", ignore_result=True)
def get_exchange_rate():
    api_url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=1"
    try:
        exchange_rate = requests.get(api_url).json()
        logger.info("BTC Exchange rate updated successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        exchange_rate = dict()
    return exchange_rate
```

Comment: Can you run the management command manually from the command line?

Comment: Yes thats working like a charm ;)
I have no idea why it should not work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone using Django 1.7+, it seems that simply import the settings module is not enough.

i got it working like this

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
import requests, os, django
from django.core import management


logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://127.0.0.1')

@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*/1')), name="Delete unused media file(s)", ignore_result=True)
def delete_unused_media():
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MyProject.settings")
    django.setup()
    try:
        print("Scanning for unused media files")
        management.call_command('cleanup_unused_media', '--noinput', '--remove-empty-dirs')
        return "success, old media files have been deleted"
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the way you're calling `call_command`. [`call_command`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#django.core.management.call_command) takes the name of the command as its first argument, followed by the arguments passed positionally. You're passing the whole lot as a single string. Try changing it to:

```
management.call_command('cleanup_unused_media', '--noinput', '--remove-empty-dirs')
```

Comment: sadly still not working :(

**
Received task: Delete unused media file(s)[96e6c763-7086-4b63-b988-d5dbf8ed5817]  
[2019-01-17 18:00:00,100: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] Scanning for unused media files
[2019-01-17 18:00:00,102: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] Unknown command: 'cleanup_unused_media'
[2019-01-17 18:00:00,103: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task Delete unused media file(s)[96e6c763-7086-4b63-b988-d5dbf8ed5817] succeeded in 0.0029836410030839033s: None**

Comment: But it seems i have this issue for all of my commands, im actually not even able to trigger syncdb or makemigration. Any idea what have been forgotten by me

Comment: Django attempts to discover the management commands by looking for them in each installed application in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Can you show how Celery has been configured/started?

Comment: i just added the lines. Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you starting the worker process? With the `celery worker` command, or with `celeryd` etc?

Comment: One thing I have spotted is that `__all__` should be specified as a tuple `__all__ = ('celery_app',)`, but note that you've specified it as a string (missing the comma)

Comment: i start celery from a diffrent script. the calls are:
celeryworker_cmdline = 'celery worker -A tasks:app -l INFO'.split(" ")
celerybeat_cmdline = 'celery -A tasks:app beat'.split(" ")